# AMPScript - Dynamically setting variable names inside a for loop

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am currently aware of the following resources:

1. [AMPScript For Loop Dynamic Variable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265579/ampscript-for-loop-dynamic-variable)
2. https://gortonington.com/dynamically-creating-variables-in-ampscript/

I have a repeating code block that I want to make DRY using a for loop. The current code is:

```
IF RowCount(@ExistingChild1) > 0 THEN
  FOR @j = 1 TO RowCount(@ExistingChild1) DO
    Set @Child1Row              = Row(@ExistingChild1,@j)
    Set @Child1SubscriberKey    = Field(@Child1Row, 'Id')
  NEXT @j
ENDIF
IF RowCount(@ExistingChild2) > 0 THEN
  FOR @j = 1 TO RowCount(@ExistingChild2) DO
    Set @Child2Row              = Row(@ExistingChild2,@j)
    Set @Child2SubscriberKey    = Field(@Child2Row, 'Id')
  NEXT @j
ENDIF
IF... /*Repeat as necessary*/
```

I have tried to create a for loop to improve my code...

```
FOR @i = TO 4 DO
  Set @currentChild = Concat('ExistingChild', @i)
  IF RowCount(@currentChild) > 0 THEN
    FOR @j = 1 TO RowCount(@currentChild) DO
      Set @Child1Row  = Row(@currentChild,@j)
      Set @fieldSet   = TreatAsContent(CONCAT('%','%[SET @Child', @i, 'SubscriberKey = Field(@Child', @i, "Row, 'Id')])%", '%'))
    NEXT @j
  ENDIF
NEXT @i
```

But this currently doesn't work. It throws the error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks.

---

### **UPDATE**

I have tested outputting a test variable which returns the below

```
testing = %%[SET @Child4SubscriberKey = Field(@ChildRow, Id)]%%
```

Comment: @currentChild's a String (eg: "ExistingChild1"), not a RowSet, so you'd not be able to loop around it. You may find SSJS a little easier to work with, here.

Comment: Hi @Macca, thanks for your answer/help. I'm pretty good with 'vanilla' JS and tried writing a for loop with template literals but it doesn't seem to work. Do you know of any resources that may help me? The actual docs don't seem to be very good.

Comment: Hi Liam.  That error is occurring because of a null reference in the C# layer, and the only thing I can see that could do that is the "field" call.  Here is the next step I would recommend:  Put everything from the CONCAT call after TreatAsContent into a string variable and see what you get.  When I have done things like this, I have often had to escape the special characters to get it to work, and you might have to do something as well.  Report back on what that string is.

Comment: Hi @Timothy - as suggested, I created a test variable to see what was being set. I have included it in an update at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is here:

```
Set @currentChild = Concat('ExistingChild', @i)
```

CONCAT will always return a string.  The code immediately following:

```
IF RowCount(@currentChild) > 0 THEN
```

RowCount takes a row set as an argument, not a string.  So this will blow up.

You will need to do some kind of LookupRows call on a DE first.